# Make a process running in background in Linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I am developing an Linux application using Python3. This application synchronizes the user's file with the cloud. The file are in a specific folder. I want that a process or daemon should run in background and whenever there is a change in that folder, It should start synchronization process.

I have made modules in Python3 for synchronization but I don't know that How to run a process in background which should **automatically detect the changes in that folder?** This process should always run in background and should be **started automatically** after boot.

Answer (score 1):

You have actually asked two distinct questions. Both have simple answers and plenty of good resources online, so I'm assuming you simply did not know what to look for.

Running a process in the background is called "daemonization". Search for "writing a daemon in python". This is a standard technique for all Posix based systems.

Monitoring a directory for changes is done through an API set called `inotify`. This is Linux specific, as each OS has its own solution.

Comment: And just to throw some software into the pool: [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) + [watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/).